# getId() on a non-object in list.phtml on search page

Tags: search, magento-1.9, getid3

I added a function to catalog/products/list.phtml to change styling for certain category. It works fine on category list but it doesn't on search page.

Error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in ../catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Added function in product image section

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 94))
```

How can I use this function but make searching working, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because, search page doesn't belong to any category or I think it's under root category..
Did you checked that search page category id??
Try to check this. I think after checking this you can find your answer..